# Deployment is ready, but nginx-ingress still has to reload and causes 503 for a few seconds

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I created a deployment using nginx-ingress, and my pods have readinessProbe and livenessProbe defined. The deployment is connected to a service and ingress to be served over a secure endpoint (e.g. https://myservice.com)

A while after the deployment has started, the pods are marked healthy, and the deployment status becomes Ready. This is great, except that nginx-ingress still has to reload the new configuration **causing a 503 for a few seconds** when trying to access the endpoint right after the deployment is marked Ready.

How do I know when the endpoint is really ready for traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx ingress now supports [dynamic updates](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/2174) on backend changes via [lua_nginx_module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) using the `balancer_by_lua` directive.

You need to pass the `--enable-dynamic-configuration=true` flag to the container arguments in the [Nginx ingress controller deployment](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml) (e.g.):

```
args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
        - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
        - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
        - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
        - --enable-dynamic-configuration=true
```

This allows an internal Lua handler to [add new endpoints](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#avoiding-reloads-on-endpoints-changes) to a shared memory zone, add some load balancing and then relay the requests to the actual backends without rewritting the configuration file in the controller.